# Controlling Django form input

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a video model that stores 'likes' as a manytomany field with User.

e.g

```
class Video(models.Model):
    ...
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    ....
```

When I create a ModelForm based on Video Likes is displayed as a dropdown with a list of all users. This is obviously ont what I want.  I would like a particular user to be able to add/ remove their own name from this list. How do I instead display 'likes' as a checkbox and still have the form validate correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your model form, create a custom field for likes; when this field is checked, set `likes` to `request.user`.

```
from django import forms

class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    likes = forms.BooleanField(label='Mark as favorite?')
    class Meta:
        model = Video
```

This will render likes as a checkbox (the default widget for [BooleanField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield)).

Answer (score 0):

I would write my own widget for this field (or replace the field with a boolean field): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets